# Cloning some records and updating one field at the same time

Tags: postgresql, performance

The need is to clone some records (with a field update at the same time).
I found three ways but not sure which is the best.

solution 1, ***LOAD IN APPLICATION***:
Fetch the records in the application, update the field, then insert the new records. (but need to fetch the records :( )

solution 2, ***INSERT INTO SELECT***: Works well but it needs to be updated when the table will change (new field for example)

```
INSERT INTO my_table (field_a, field_b, field_c)
      SELECT  42, mt.field_b, mt.field_c
      FROM    my_table as mt
      WHERE   lc.field_a = 45;
```

solution 3, ***TEMPORARY TABLE*** Is this ok ?

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * INTO TEMPORARY temp_my_table FROM my_table WHERE field_a = 45;
UPDATE temp_my_table SET field_a = 42;
INSERT INTO my_table SELECT * FROM temp_my_table;
DROP TABLE temp_my_table;
END;
```

What is the best solution, assuming from 10 to 1000 records?

Is the third idea ok for concurrent executions?

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Thank you for pointing this, it's fixed.

Comment: Option 2 looks the best, but what does `the application needs to know all the fields` and `the request have to be updated for each table modification` mean?

Comment: It means that if someone adds a new field in the targetted table, we have to update the "clone" request.

Comment: I don't understand! In 2 you have 42 & 45 and in 3 you have 42 & 51 - and the SQLs, even if you had one of 45 or 51 in both, don't do the same thing. If what you want to do is really 3, then I might be inclined to use a CTE which elegantly takes care of the lot in one statement - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0fc0c9173d8ae4f547fc26a7b154cdcc). If this sorts your problem, I will write  it up as an answer if you like?

Comment: I've fixed the differences between the two requests. The need is just to clone few records and at the same time update one field. The question is about performance and maintainability.

Comment: I would like to know if solution 3 is ok for concurrent executions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your option 2 is the "normal" solution.

Yes, your query *will* need changing if the table structure changes (unless all the new fields are nullable).  However, [lots of] *other* code will need changing as well, to make use of the new field, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: What about the 3?

Comment: You'd be writing (and, therefore, logging) the data twice.  For the number of rows you're currently working with, that's not a problem but once this is in place, somebody's going to ask to run it a million rows - not so good.  
You cannot "hide" from schema & code changes and their need to "match up".

Comment: Ok, thank you. I decided to use solution 2 and added an automated test that will fail if someone adds a new field to the table, to inform that this request must be updated.